# SQLite Android loading endless list gives wrong data sequence

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am loading messages from an android **sqlite** database.

Here is what I want to do:

I have a number of chat rooms identified by a roomName variable.

They are all storing their messages on an sqlite database table.

I want to open the conversation in a chat room, load the 10 most recent messages using the name of the chat room and display on the `ListView`.. by adding the messages to its `BaseAdapter` (backed by an `ArrayList`).

If the user scrolls to the bottom, I want to load the 10 next recent messages and dump into the ListView's adapter...and so on.

Unfortunately, using the current queries that I wrote, sometimes the output in the adapter gets a bit disorderly.

For example when I entered the chat sequence,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.....62, (Each number is an individual message)

When I viewed the output in the listview, I got:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13..etc.

Here is my code below...(the Post object models each chat message, and each ChatRoom object maintains an ArrayList of Posts)

```
/**
 * @param numOfMessagesGottenAlready The number of messages that the    
 * room has already.
 * @param numOfMessagesNeeded The additional number of messages to load.
 * @param roomName The name of the ChatRoom
 * @return an ArrayList of messages loaded in pagination style..with the   
 * most recent at the bottom.
 */
public ArrayList<Post> getRecentPosts(int numOfMessagesGottenAlready,int numOfMessagesNeeded,String roomName) {
            //SQLiteDatabase db = AppController.databaseUtils.getReadableDatabase();
        int add = numOfMessagesGottenAlready + numOfMessagesNeeded;
        //boolean success = true;
        try {
            Cursor res = AppController.contentResolver.query(ChatsProvider.CONTENT_URI_CHATS, new String[]{"COUNT("+ROOMS_COLUMN_ID+")"},
                    ROOM_NAME+" = ? ", new String[]{roomName}, ROOMS_COLUMN_ID+" DESC " );

            res.moveToFirst();

            int count = res.getInt(0);

            if (!res.isClosed()) {
                res.close();
            }



            if (count >= numOfMessagesGottenAlready) {
                Cursor set = AppController.contentResolver.query(ChatsProvider.CONTENT_URI_CHATS, new String[]{ROOMS_COLUMN_JSON},
                        ROOM_NAME+" = ? ", new String[]{roomName}, ROOMS_COLUMN_ID+" ASC LIMIT "+numOfMessagesNeeded +
                                " OFFSET ("+(count - add) + " )" );

                set.moveToFirst();
                ArrayList<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    while (!set.isAfterLast()) {
                        posts.add(Post.parseJsonToPost(
                                set.getString(set.getColumnIndex(ROOMS_COLUMN_JSON))));
                        set.moveToNext();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return posts;
                }
                if (!set.isClosed()) {
                    set.close();
                }

                return posts;


            }

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }


        return new ArrayList<Post>();

}
```

Please what mistake am I making in the SQL statement, or perhaps the java code?

Thanks!

Comment: While a laudable goal, there probably isn't a great reason to do the paging yourself.  Just use a CursorLoader and a SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. But can you spot any error in my code, please?